# How to calculate $\int \frac{1}{1+\exp(-r\sin(tx))}\,dx$

Tags: integration

How would one calculate the indefinite integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+\exp(-r\sin(tx))}\,dx,$$

where $r >0,t>0$ are some constants? Should I use series expansion? Definite integral solution would also be of assistance.

UPDATE:

This problem originates from my application of generalized linear models where my link function is a composition of a sigmoid and a sine function. I'm trying to formulate the Akaike information criterion for sinusoidal binary classifier.

Comment: I'm afraid that that *indefinite* integral is completely hopeless...If it were a *definite* integral maybe something could be done.

Comment: what makes you think an answer exists? wolfram alpha is dumbfounded...

Comment: If I may ask : is this monster coming from a nightmare or is there a context for this integral ?

Comment: First, I do not know whether an answer exists. Second, no, it is not coming from a nightmare but from my application of generalized linear models where my link function is a composition of a sigmoid and a sine function. I'm trying to formulate the Akaike information criterion for sinusoidal binary classifier.

Comment: Good to know the context. I am skeptical about  the indefinite integral. May be, for the definite integral some approximations could be done. I shall look at it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

If, as qbert suggested in a comment, we make the approximation $\exp(-r\sin(tx))\approx 1-r\sin(tx)$, we then have
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{1+\exp\left(-r\sin(tx)\right)}\approx \int\frac{dx}{2-r \sin (t x)}=-\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{r-2 \tan \left(\frac{t
   x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}\right)}{t\sqrt{4-r^2} }\tag 1$$

If we continue the expansion
$$\exp(-r\sin(tx))\approx 1-r\sin(tx)+\frac 12 r^2 \sin^2(tx)$$ we can still integrate and get the ugly
$$I\approx \frac{2 }{t\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{r-\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \tan
   \left(\frac{t x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{-r^2+2 i \sqrt{3}-2}}\right)}{\sqrt{r^2+2-2 i
   \sqrt{3}}}-\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{r-\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \tan
   \left(\frac{t x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{-r^2-2 i \sqrt{3}-2}}\right)}{\sqrt{r^2+2+2 i
   \sqrt{3}}}\right)\tag 2$$

**Edit**

Let $tx=y$ which makes
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{1+\exp\left(-r\sin(tx)\right)}=\frac 1t \int \frac{dy}{1+\exp\left(-r\sin(y)\right)}$$ and compute 
$$J=\int_0^a \frac{dy}{1+\exp\left(-r\sin(y)\right)}$$ for a few values to get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
r & a & \text{exact} & (1) & (2) \\
 0.25 & 0.1 & 0.050312 & 0.050315 & 0.050312 \\
 0.25 & 0.2 & 0.101246 & 0.101267 & 0.101245 \\
 0.25 & 0.3 & 0.152791 & 0.152863 & 0.152789 \\
 0.25 & 0.4 & 0.204932 & 0.205101 & 0.204928 \\
 0.25 & 0.5 & 0.257646 & 0.257975 & 0.257636 \\
 0.25 & 0.6 & 0.310907 & 0.311470 & 0.310887 \\
 0.25 & 0.7 & 0.364681 & 0.365560 & 0.364644 \\
 0.25 & 0.8 & 0.418929 & 0.420216 & 0.418869 \\
 0.25 & 0.9 & 0.473609 & 0.475396 & 0.473517 \\
 0.25 & 1.0 & 0.528673 & 0.531053 & 0.528541 \\
      &     &          &          &          \\ 
 0.50 & 0.1 & 0.050624 & 0.050635 & 0.050624 \\
 0.50 & 0.2 & 0.102491 & 0.102578 & 0.102488 \\
 0.50 & 0.3 & 0.155578 & 0.155875 & 0.155567 \\
 0.50 & 0.4 & 0.209852 & 0.210564 & 0.209816 \\
 0.50 & 0.5 & 0.265265 & 0.266665 & 0.265179 \\
 0.50 & 0.6 & 0.321759 & 0.324180 & 0.321583 \\
 0.50 & 0.7 & 0.379263 & 0.383092 & 0.378946 \\
 0.50 & 0.8 & 0.437698 & 0.443360 & 0.437174 \\
 0.50 & 0.9 & 0.496976 & 0.504919 & 0.496170 \\
 0.50 & 1.0 & 0.557002 & 0.567677 & 0.555831 \\
      &     &          &          &          \\ 
 0.75 & 0.1 & 0.050936 & 0.050961 & 0.050936 \\
 0.75 & 0.2 & 0.103734 & 0.103935 & 0.103726 \\
 0.75 & 0.3 & 0.158357 & 0.159053 & 0.158318 \\
 0.75 & 0.4 & 0.214748 & 0.216435 & 0.214623 \\
 0.75 & 0.5 & 0.272828 & 0.276184 & 0.272521 \\
 0.75 & 0.6 & 0.332500 & 0.338375 & 0.331867 \\
 0.75 & 0.7 & 0.393651 & 0.403054 & 0.392499 \\
 0.75 & 0.8 & 0.456155 & 0.470221 & 0.454241 \\
 0.75 & 0.9 & 0.519874 & 0.539828 & 0.516918 \\
 0.75 & 1.0 & 0.584663 & 0.611767 & 0.580363 \\
      &     &          &          &          \\ 
 1.00 & 0.1 & 0.051248 & 0.051292 & 0.051247 \\
 1.00 & 0.2 & 0.104975 & 0.105341 & 0.104957 \\
 1.00 & 0.3 & 0.161125 & 0.162410 & 0.161029 \\
 1.00 & 0.4 & 0.219610 & 0.222767 & 0.219298 \\
 1.00 & 0.5 & 0.280309 & 0.286674 & 0.279541 \\
 1.00 & 0.6 & 0.343080 & 0.354373 & 0.341490 \\
 1.00 & 0.7 & 0.407757 & 0.426074 & 0.404851 \\
 1.00 & 0.8 & 0.474159 & 0.501929 & 0.469328 \\
 1.00 & 0.9 & 0.542097 & 0.582009 & 0.534637 \\
 1.00 & 1.0 & 0.611372 & 0.666278 & 0.600530
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can go further with as many terms as wished in the expansion of the exponential using
$$1+\exp\left(-r\sin(y)\right)=2+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(r\sin(y))^k$$ So, let the $a_i$'s to be the roots of the polynomial
$$2+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}z^k=0$$ If $n$ is even, all roots will be complex; if $n$ is odd, only one real root.

Now, using partial fraction decomposition to get by the end
$$\frac 1{2+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(r\sin(y))^k}=n!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {b_k}{r\sin(y)-a_k}$$ making
$$\int \frac {dy}{2+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(r\sin(y))^k}=2n!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b_k }{\sqrt{a_k^2-r^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{r-a_k \tan
   \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{a_k^2-r^2}}\right)$$

Integrating for $0$ to $1$, we should get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 r &  \text{exact} & n=1 & n=2 & n=3 & n=4 & n=5 \\
 0.25 & 0.528673 & 0.531053 & 0.528541 & 0.528679 & 0.528673 & 0.528673 \\
 0.50 & 0.557002 & 0.567677 & 0.555831 & 0.557106 & 0.556994 & 0.557002 \\
 0.75 & 0.584663 & 0.611767 & 0.580363 & 0.585252 & 0.584599 & 0.584669 \\
 1.00 & 0.611372 & 0.666278 & 0.600530 & 0.613421 & 0.611072 & 0.611410 \\
 1.25 & 0.636895 & 0.736151 & 0.614934 & 0.642362 & 0.635901 & 0.637052 \\
 1.50 & 0.661057 & 0.830489 & 0.622695 & 0.673416 & 0.658420 & 0.661563 \\
 1.75 & 0.683742 & 0.968709 & 0.623655 & 0.708808 & 0.677773 & 0.685103 \\
 2.00 & 0.704888 & 1.204110 & 0.618349 & 0.752337 & 0.692940 & 0.708099
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! =) nice work!

Comment: @jjepsuomi. Yesterday, I promised to work this problem after you told it is not coming from a nightmare but serious. I hope this will be of some help to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your effort and hope it will also provide help to others. Important job you guys do ;)

Comment: One more question about equation $(2)$ which involves complex numbers. Do the imaginary numbers always cancel out in the last column of the table for equation $(2)$? Or can the table contain complex numbers?

Comment: @jjepsuomi. Not at all; the results are real numbers (as expected).

Comment: Just to clarify final thing :) So, the $I$ in equation $(2)$ is a mapping: $I(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ even though the expression contains complex numbers?

Comment: One more question, how are $b_k$s defined?

Comment: @jjepsuomi. I am afraid that, for $n>4$, the $a_k,b_k$ must be computed numerically since you need the roots of a polynomial.

Comment: Thank you @ClaudeLeibovici. I'm especially interested on the part where you do the partial fraction decompositioning (the last two equations of your answer). It would be nice to know how you arrived at those equations. Also, it would be super if you could shortly show/explain how you would calculate the $a_k$s and  $b_k$s when $n>4$, say $n=5$. My goal would be to actually implement these functions in a computer program. One technical note also, I would want the constant $r$ to be very large, say $r=100000$ because I want the sigmoid to resemble $sign$-function as much as possible.

Comment: @jjepsuomi. This is just partial fraction decomposition. The problem is that everything needs to be done numerically with a lot of care to avoid losses of accuracy. For given $n$, solve the equation to get the roots $a_k$; then compute the corresponding $b_k$ with the usual trick.

Comment: Excellent, thank you :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi. You are very welcome ! From a numerical point of view, it is a very interesting problem (when knowing that it did not come from a nightmare). Since you need to generate the values of $(a_k,b_k)$ only once, use the most extended precision you can afford. Cheers.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I will do that. Appreciate your effort! If and when I get it done, I will post the results here :)

Answer (score 8):

I trust Wolfram alpha in that the indefinite integral is hopeless. However, if you happen to encounter this integrand as a definite integral over a symmetric interval, then things do work out  nicely and you may compute as follows
$$
I=\int_{-a}^a\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(-r\sin(tx)\right)}\mathrm dx=
\int_{-a}^a\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(r\sin(tx)\right)}\mathrm dx
$$
By a standard symmetry argument. Then, 
$$
2I=\int_{-a}^a\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(-r\sin(tx)\right)}+
\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(r\sin(tx)\right)}\mathrm dx\\
=\int_{-a}^a\frac{2+\exp\left(-r\sin(tx)\right)+\exp\left(r\sin(tx)\right)}{2+\exp\left(-r\sin(tx)\right)+\exp\left(r\sin(tx)\right)}\mathrm dx=2a
$$
and $I=a$.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I think it did help, good to know that my problem is hard. Maybe I need to try another approach. Thank you! One more question, so series like Maclaurin series are of no help here?

Comment: Im not particularly qualified to answer this, and i am not sure of the context (like how accurate you need it to be) but you could certainly calculate an antiderivative after approximating $\exp(-r\sin(tx))\approx 1-r\sin(tx)$

Comment: My field is data analysis, machine learning, and this problem is not part of any research but just out of my personal curiosity. Many textbook examples have very nice and well-behaving functions and I wanted to give it a go and try the theories out with something custom made. I could definitely try that approximation, thank you =)

Comment: Thank you @qbert for your help, hope you don't mind if I however accept Claude Leibovici's answer, because that answer is little bit closer (even though your answer contributed to it) to what I need.

Comment: Of course, feel free!

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-\exp (-x))^n=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

and:

$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^j}{j!}=\exp (x)$$

so,

$\color{red}{\int \frac{1}{1+\exp (-r \sin (t x))} \, dx}=\\
=\int \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } (-1)^n e^{-n r \sin (t x)}\right) \, dx\\=
\int \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \left(\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^j n^j r^j \sin ^j(t x)}{j!}\right)\right) \, dx\\
=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \int
   \frac{(-1)^j n^j r^j \sin ^j(t x)}{j!} \, dx\right)\\
=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{1+j+n} n^j r^j \cos (t x) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-j}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(t x)\right) \sin ^{1+j}(t x) \sin ^2(t x)^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{j}{2}}}{t j!}\right)\\
=\color{red}{\sum
   _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{1+j} r^j \cos (t x) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-j}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(t x)\right) \sin ^{1+j}(t x) \sin ^2(t
   x)^{\frac{1}{2} (-1-j)} \left(2^j \zeta (-j,0)+\left(-1+2^j\right) \zeta (-j)\right)}{t j!}+C}$

where:
$\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-j}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos ^2(t x)\right)$ is [Hypergeometric2F1](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/17/ShowAll.html)

$ \zeta (-j,0)$,$\zeta (-j)$ is [HurwitzZeta](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta2/) and Zeta.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Appreciate it! Indeed it is a nasty beast x)